# изображение при повороте уменьшается

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

вот такой кусок кода, отвечающий за поворот изображения на n угол. изображение должно только повернуться, но почему-то еще уменьшается и растягивается

```
public Bitmap rotate(Bitmap img, float angle)
        {
            double radius = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(img.Width, 2) + Math.Pow(img.Height, 2));
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap((int)radius, (int)radius);
            Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
            gr.TranslateTransform((float)radius / 2, (float)radius / 2);
            gr.RotateTransform(angle);
            gr.ScaleTransform(img.Width / (float)radius, img.Height / (float)radius);
            gr.TranslateTransform(-(float)radius / 2.0f, -(float)radius / 2.0f);
            gr.DrawImageUnscaled(img, new Point(0, 0));

            pictureBox1.Image = bm;
            return bm;
        }
```

Comment: А вы разве не делаете уменьшения в scaletransform?

Comment: убрал - помогло избавиться от искажения фото, но осталась проблема, что оно "отдаляется". через несколько таких поворотов невозможно что-либо рассмотреть. уменьшается сильно

Comment: Вы применяете поворот к изначальной картинке или постоянно ее обновляете?

Comment: постоянно обновляю. в конце стоит return, изображение возвращается, записывается в переменную и передается (уже измененное) снова при следующем вызове

Comment: Это неправильно, накапливаются искажения. Нужно хранить начальную картинку и к ней применять поворот

Comment: я бы с радостью, но таково задание

Comment: Как оно звучит?

Comment: в самом задании этого не написано, так сказал преподаватель

Comment: `Скажите государю, что у англичан ружья кирпичом не чистят`©Лесков  Это порочный путь. Кроме геометрических искажений, качество при каждом повороте чуть падает, и постепенно картинка размоется. Ну ладно. Размер заметно меняется при каждом повороте, или постепенно?

Comment: заметно. через пару оборотов уже невозможно прочитать текст. мне кажется проблема из-за pictureBox, я не силен в .net так что не могу понять в чем беда

Comment: Покажите реальный текущий код

Comment: уже решил проблему. поменял код, нашел похожую задачу в интернете.